# Retrieving JSON using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I'm tinkering with JSON data for the first time. Some examples I have found online seem very complex and I am having trouble simplifying it so that I can understand the file. I decided to make a blog website that would use JSON data to populate it. All files are external to HTML file. JS file has been properly linked. JS file is in js folder of root. The index.html and blogs.json are in root directory.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="blog_list"> <!-- Div to hold populated blogs -->

<!-- Blog Start -->
<div class="blog_post"> 
  <div class="blog_panel">
    <img class="blog_image" src="" alt="">
    <div class="blog_panel_body">
      <h2 class="blog_title"></h2>
      <span class="blog_author_date"></span>
      <p class="blog_content">

      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Blog End -->

</div>
```

Here's the external JSON data:

```
{
"blogs": [
    {
    "img": "<img class=\"image\" src=\"img/image.jpeg\" alt=\"Sample image 1\" />",
    "title": "My Amazing Journey",
    "author": "David",
    "date": "June 13, 2017",
    "content": "This is some content."
    },
    {
    "img": "<img src=\"img/image.jpeg\" alt=\"Sample image 2\" />",
    "title": "My Beautiful Journey",
    "author": "David",
    "date": "June 14, 2017",
    "content": "This is some content."
    },
    {
    "img": "<img src=\"img/image.jpeg\" alt=\"Sample image 3\" />",
    "title": "My Wonderful Journey",
    "author": "David",
    "date": "June 15, 2017",
    "content": "This is some content."
    }]
}
```

Here's my external JS file:

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("./blogs.json"), function(json) {
        json.blogs.forEach(function(blog) {
            var newBlog = $('body').find(".blog_post").clone();
            $(newBlog).find(".blog_image").html(blog.img);
            $(newBlog).find(".blog_title").append(blog.title);
            $(newBlog).find(".blog_author_date").append("Written by: " + blog.author + " on " + blog.date);
            $(newBlog).find(".blog_content").append(blog.content);
        });
    };
});
```

The console shows the error:

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed Location: file:///Users/David/Site/Website%20Template/blogs.json Line Number 1, Column 1:  blogs.json:1:1
```

Am I on the right track? Any advice and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: delete `json =` from your `blogs.json` file and it should work

Comment: That did fix the syntax error. Now the console shows: XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: file:///Users/David/Sites/Website%20Template/blogs.json
Line Number 1, Column 1:  blogs.json:1:1

Comment: I think you need to configure your webserver's `mime.types` file so it returns the MIME type `application/json` for the `.json` extension.

Comment: @Barmar I will set up web server to try that. I was running from finder on mac.

Comment: I'm not sure what finder is but have you tried running it in firefox? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21507816/getjson-is-not-working-in-chrome

Comment: @HastigZusammenstellen Finder is the windows explorer for mac. I opened file by right clicking index and selecting open with firefox.

Comment: I get the same error in firefox (xml parsing error) all the time but I'm still able to load the json data. Have you tried cutting the code down to something simple that you know will work and testing if it loads it into your html?

Comment: @HastigZusammenstellen I added text js file that would simply get the JSON so I could look at the returned object but to no avail. I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't address your exact jquery problem (using clone) but here's another way to go about what I think you want to do..

**test.html** (in root folder)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>json/js test stack question</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/test.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="blog_list">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**test.json** (in root folder)

```
{"blogs": [
    {
    "img": "blog1.jpg",
    "title": "My Amazing Journey",
    "author": "David",
    "date": "June 13, 2017",
    "content": "This is some content."
    },
    {
    "img": "blog2.jpg",
    "title": "My Beautiful Journey",
    "author": "David",
    "date": "June 14, 2017",
    "content": "This is some content."
    },
    {
    "img": "blog3.jpg",
    "title": "My Wonderful Journey",
    "author": "David",
    "date": "June 15, 2017",
    "content": "This is some content."
    }
]}
```

**test.js** (in js folder which is in root folder)

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON("./test.json", function(json) {
        var opener = '<!-- Blog Start --><div class="blog_post"><div class="blog_panel">';
        var closer = '</div></div><!-- Blog End -->';
        $(json.blogs).each(function() {
            var body = '' +
                '<img class="blog_image" src="folder/' + this.img + '" alt="' + this.title + '">' +
                '<div class="blog_panel_body">' +
                  '<h2 class="blog_title">' + this.title + '</h2>' +
                  '<span class="blog_author_date">' + this.author + ':' + this.date + '</span>' +
                  '<p class="blog_content">' + this.content + '</p>' +
                '</div>'
            ;
            $('.blog_list').append(opener + body + closer);
        })
    });
})
```

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thanks. Could it be the "./" in the json path

Comment: I think i have the folder structyre recreated exactly as you now and im using the ./ in folder path. ill update the answer to show my folder and files setup..

Comment: @DavidG I updated the answer with something I got to work. I don't think I'll have time to play with your .clone method of doing things as I'm not overfly familiar with it but may play with it later tonight for practice. Let me know if you can get this to work for you.

Comment: That works well enough for me. I found that code somewhere online, but I'm not married to it lol. Thanks for the help. Let me know if any reason becomes apparent of why that clone() was in there. I figured it was to duplicate the HTML for holding blogs so maybe it would simplify your code. Don't know. Yours works! Good enough for me. Thanks for dedicating your time to helping me.

Comment: I think you're right, using .clone would help prevent cluttering up the js file with too much html. You can just put the template in your html, use jquery to clone it and keep html in .html and js in .js. It's a little trickier though and something I'll have to look into incorporating into future scripts as I usually use the exact, simplistic style I used in my answer here. Good luck with your project. :)